# Add carriage return and line feed after Head tag to Action Rewrite Value in IIS Rewrite Rule Module outbound rule

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, carriage-return, url-rewrite-module, linefeed

I'm working on dynamically adding a script block using an `IIS` `URL Rewrite Rule` (outbound). The script block should begin right after the `HTML` `head` tag. It works as intended. The only problem is I'd like to place the script block on a new and possibly indent. I'd like to add a `carriage return` and `line feed` to the `Action Rewrite Value`.

Here is what I have thus far:

[image]

After URL Rewrite processes, the source file resembles:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="webanalytics.js"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test Page">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

What I desire is this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webanalytics.js"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test Page">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Can this be done with the IIS URL Rewrite Rule module?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement, generally people want to remove white-space to make the page load faster, why add it? Anyway, have you tried the standard `\r\n` escape sequence? (not sure if its valid in this context)

Comment: I'm adding web analytics to every page, dynamically. This is standard fare procedure to add the script block at the web server processing level. I have tried \r\n escape sequence, yes. My guess is I'll have to work on improving the regular expression match to get the desired outcome. My opinion is I don't think Microsoft designed the Action Rewrite Value to be used in the manner I'm attempting. Regex capability is limited, as well. Inline modifier regex flags do not work, either.

Comment: i get your adding a script - i dont get why you care about the whitespace. The HTML you currently have is valid, the other new lines in your snippet are also optional (ie the <head>...</head> could be placed on a single line). if your goal is consistency, minify your markup - it will (among other things) remove the carriage returns

Comment: Nobody reads your HTML but the browser engines. So formatted or not does not matter. There is no need to be a perfectionist here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback.

I did manage to get the formatting/indenting how I preferred. Yes, nobody reads the source code but the browser engine. But I prefer to maintain format consistency for testing and troubleshooting client-side issues.

**Pattern:**

```
(<head.*?>(\s*))
```

**(Action) Value:**

```
{R:1}<script type="text/javascript" src="webanalytics.js"></script>{R:2}
```